# Compute multiple arrays of same variables into one Variables in R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, spss

How to compute different parameters as one in R. For example. I have 3 arrays of a variable A called A1.1,A1.2,A1.3. I want to compute them in one as "A". How to do that?

```
A1.1>c(1,1,1,0,0,0)
A1.2>c(1,0,0,1,1,1)
A1.3>c(0,1,1,1,1,1)
```

Out put should be like this. in SPSS we do this by compute variables.

```
A>c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what calculation you are making to reach that output. Could you demonstrate with the SPSS syntax? did you try any R code?

Comment: Well i have clinical data. Lets say this is smoking status of patients. where 1 says smoker and o says non-smoker. We have three observations here. A1.1 is at his first visit to doctor. A1.2 is his second visit to doctor and A1.3 is his third visit to doctor. So I just want one variable called A which may summerise the three visits observation. Like any patient has "1" in any array, in output it shud be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R you can use simple math on arrays, for example:

```
A1.1 <- c(1,0,1,0,0,0)
A1.2 <- c(1,0,0,1,1,1)
A1.3 <- c(0,0,1,1,1,1)
A1 <-  1*((A1.1 + A1.2 + A1.3)>0)

> A1
[1] 1 0 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In R you can use the `any()` function inside of `apply()` to make this check.  For example:

```
a1 <- c(1,0,0,0,1,1)
a2 <- c(0,1,0,0,0,1)
a3 <- c(0,1,1,0,1,1)
a <- apply(data.frame(a1,a2,a3), 1, function(x) ifelse(any(x),1,0))
```

And then as output:

```
> a
[1] 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

In SPSS you can take a similar approach:

```
COMPUTE a = ANY(1, a1 TO a3) .
EXE .
```

Comment: For spss this can also work: `compute a = max(a1 to a3)`